# Regex find comment word and replace comment1

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I am looking for a regular expression  that would allow me to find and replace all instances with id="comment"  with adding incremental number.  Like id="comment1", id="comment2" and so on.  I have about 400+ instances in an HTML document.

Should I use notepad++?   What is the easiest way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what might be the easiest way, but I highly doubt that'd be any regular expression.

Maybe, with a for loop we could do that. For instance, it would look something like this in PHP:

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents('path/to/html/file/filename.html');
$arr = preg_split('/id="comment"/', $str);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $count = $key + 1;
    if ($key == sizeof($arr) - 1) {
        $new_str .= $value;
    } else {
        $new_str .= $value . ' id="comment' . $count . '"';
    }
}

$str = file_put_contents('path/to/html/file/filename_modified.html', $new_str);
```

Comment: I tried to replace id="comment" with (id=\"comment([0-9]+)?\") in notepad++ and it didn't work

Comment: Not sure how to use php

Comment: English..  LOL JK  I am not a programmer.  I mess with HTML

Comment: How would I also give the same number to data-clipboard-target="#comment" ?

Comment: Can I use the php script above instead?  Then add the additional value.  That way id=comment1 will be the same for data-clipboard-target="#comment1"

Comment: I would like to use the php script you provided, but I forgot that I have the button target that needs to be the same as the ID for the textarea https://regex101.com/r/9aIM1Z/1

Comment: More like this:  https://regex101.com/r/qWhROg/2
When it still counts up but assisgn the same unique number to each button and target

Comment: Does that make sense?  I want to do the same thing in the php file you gave me, but add data-clipboard-target="#comment" to the search and give the same comment number as the ID="comment"

Comment: What woudl I need to add to your solution to complete that task?

Comment: Okay, Thank you.  It worked.  I was making things harder than it was.